# Why vector.size()-1 gives garbage value?

Tags: c++, debugging, vector, issue-tracking

I had tried running this code

```
// vector::size
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main ()
{
   std::vector<int> myints;
   std::cout << "size: " << myints.size() << '\n';
   std::cout << "size: " << myints.size()-1 << '\n';

 return 0; 
}
```

And Surprisingly the output came

> 0
>
> garbage Value

It should be

> 0
>
> -1

Here's the :[code](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/xnwX6SGg56)

Comment: Look at the type.

Comment: I seriously doubt that your program literally output "garbage Value".

Comment: It should not be. It's an unsigned type, there are no negative values.

Comment: @molbdnilo: That's a good question. I need to check but I *think* the behaviour of `cout` is implementation defined for `unsigned` types over a certain size. Seems that theoretically, "garbage Value" is allowed by the standard.

Comment: @Bathsheba, As far as I can tell from `operator<<` and `num_put::do_put`, an `unsigned long long` with default other settings will be output the same way as a call to `printf("%ull", val)`, and likewise for other fundamental unsigned types. I'm not so sure you'd have a potential problem from `size_t`, given that it would either fit an overload or cause an ambiguity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`myints.size()` is an *unsigned* type: formally a `std::vector<int>::size_type`. Subtracting `1` from an unsigned type with a value of 0 will cause wrap-around effects, in your case, to

```
std::numeric_limits<std::vector<int>::size_type>::max()
```

It would **not** have printed "garbage value": but the number above, which will be one less than a large power of 2.